# Order by most matched records first

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following query:

```
select * from users 
where first_name ilike '%foo%' 
OR last_name ilike '%bar%' 
OR nickname ilike '%foobar%'
```

Returns:

```
 first_name| last_name   |  nickname
----------------------------------------
  Foo      | ABC         |   abcd
  Foo      | DEF         |   efgh
  Foo      | BAR         |   ijkl
  AMD      | Bar         |   foobar
  Foo      | Bar         |   foobar2
```

**Question:**

How to sort most relevant (matched) values first?
I mean by most matched that matches more than one pattern inside `Where .. OR`

**Expected Result:**

```
 first_name| last_name   |  nickname
----------------------------------------
  Foo      | Bar         |   foobar2
  Foo      | BAR         |   ijkl
  AMD      | Bar         |   foobar
  Foo      | ABC         |   abcd
  Foo      | DEF         |   efgh
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Order it by the number of hits:

```
... ORDER BY (first_name ILIKE '%foo%')::integer 
           + (last_name  ILIKE '%bar%')::integer
           + (nickname   ILIKE '%foobar%')::integer DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

you need UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(col1, col2) ([link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/utl_match-string-matching-in-oracle))

```
select * from users 
where first_name ilike '%foo%' 
OR last_name ilike '%bar%' 
OR nickname ilike '%foobar%'
order by UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(first_name, 'foo')
   + UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(last_name, 'bar')
   + UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(nickname, 'foobar')
```

UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity returns the percentage of similarity, i.e.

- Superman = Superman => 100 [%]
- Superman = supermon => 88 [%]

**Edit**:Aaah, you specified PostGreSql, that's oracle. But as I already got a like it's perhaps right anyway... **Edit3**:As Laurenz Albe mentioned in the comments, there is definitly no utl_matcvh in postgreSql. So you need to use the module or his approach. I'll leave this answer for completeness.

**Edit2**: To check similarity in PostGreSql you can use the module [fuzzystrmatch](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) Example:

> *The fuzzystrmatch module provides two functions for working with
>   Soundex codes:*
>
> soundex(text) returns text and difference(text, text) returns int

```
SELECT soundex('Anne'), soundex('Ann'), difference('Anne', 'Ann');
```

Comment: There is no `UTL_MATCH` in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I extended my answer depending on your comment @LaurenzAlbe but left it as it mentions the module fuzzystrmatch.